# Import an Excel file with data and create new table to sql and copy the data from imported excel file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please help me on how to import excel data to SQL Server(create new table) using Visual Basic 2010 or Store Procedure.

Any one knows? Please give me some ideas on how to start .

Thanks.

**Excel File**

```
FirstName     LastName
John          Cruz
Jonard        Reyes
```

**Customer Table in SQL**

```
FirstName     LastName
John          Cruz
Jonard        Reyes
```

Comment: Reference [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/385368/how-to-import-exel-file-to-sql-server-using-vb-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Import table from Excel into SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822562/vba-import-table-from-excel-into-sql)

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server Integration Services? That's sort of what it's for...

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.